# ngDraggable not working for content loaded with innerHtml angular2+

Tags: html, angular, innerhtml, ngdraggable

I am getting an HTML file from the backend, that I am displaying in angular with inner HTML in a div tag. In that, ngDraggable in HTML file is not recognized, which is not processed by angular as like directive.

Angular:

```
<div *ngIf="content" class="content" [innerHTML]="sanitize.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content)"></div>
```

Html from backend:

```
    <div class="container" contenteditable="true" id="div0" style="position : relative;">
  <div id="div1" style="position : relative; margin : 2%; height : 554.5px">
    <input class="form-control" id="textbox1" name="textbox1" style="top : 195.21px; left : 297.61px;  position : absolute; width : 20%;" type="text">
    <button ngDraggable class="btn-primary" id="button1" style="top : 367.03px; left : 189.82px;  position : absolute;">Button</button>

  </div>
</div>
```

In this, on button tag, I am giving ngDraggable that I am no able to drag after loaded to angular from backend

Comment: Can you please provide the StackBlitz sample for the issue?

Comment: @JinsThomasShaji now check

Comment: In this case, the above HTMl code will be considered as static text only. While adding directive, angular will compile the directive to perform the actions. Since the above piece of code will be placed after compilation(runtime), `ngDraggable` will be considered as an attribute of `button` only, which is meaningless. So for satisfying requirement, you have to change the approach.

Comment: @JinsThomasShaji Is there any way to add that attribute at runtime. I am getting HTML from the backend of type string.